# JWT token cannot be set to header (Node & express.js)

Tags: node.js, express, mongodb-query

I'm working on a Node backend that uses MongoDB as its database. When I should send my JWT token within the response header, I get an error that the headers cannot be set after they are sent to the client. Here is my POST request:

```
api.post("/account/create", async (req, res) => {

    // Hash the password using bcrypt
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);

    // Store new login credentials
    const user = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: hashedPassword
    };

    // Create a new JWT token
    const token = jwt.sign({ username: req.body.username }, secret);

    // Search for a matching username from the database
    await logincollection.findOne(user, (err, result) => {

        // If username was not found, add the credentials to the database
        if (result == null) {

            // Insert the credentials to the login credentials collection
            logincollection.insertOne(user, (err, result) => {

                // If an error occurred, return code 404 to the client
                if (err) {
                    res.status(404).send();
                }

            })

            // Create personal collection for the user
            userdb.createCollection(JSON.stringify(user.username), (err, result) => {

                // If an error occurred, return code 404 to the client
                if (err) {
                    res.status(404).send();
                }

            })

            // Return code 200 (success)
            res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token });

        } else {

            // If username was found, return code 400 to the client
            res.status(400).send();

        }

    })

})
```

When I try to get the token value in another POST request, it returns `undefined`:

```
api.post("/account/login", async (req, res) => {

    // User object
    const user = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    const token = req.headers["token"];
    console.log(token);

    // Get username as a string
    const username = JSON.stringify(user.username);

    // Get hashed password from the collection
    const hashedPassword = await logincollection.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    console.log(hashedPassword);

    // Search for matching login credentials
    await logincollection.find(user, (err, result) => {

        // If no token was given
        if (!token) {

            // Return code 401 to the client
            res.status(401).send();

        }

        // Verify the given JWT token
        jwt.verify(token, secret, (err, decoded) => {

            // If verification failed
            if (err) {

                // Return code 500 to the client
                res.status(500).send();

            }

            // Return code 200 and decoded token to the client
            res.status(200).send(decoded);

        })

            // Use bcrypt to compare the passwords and authenticate login
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, hashedPassword).then(match => {

                // If the credentials match
                if (match) {

                    // Return the result as an object
                    const sendObject = {
                        username: result.username,
                        password: result.password
                    };

                    // Return code 200 to the client
                    res.status(200).send(sendObject);

                    // Log to console when user logs in
                    console.log("User " + username + " logged in");

                // If the credentials do not match
                } else {

                    // Return code 404 to the client
                    res.status(404).send();

                }

            // If comparing fails
            }).catch(error => {

                // Return coe 500 to the client
                res.status(500).send();

            })

    })

})
```

I'm pretty sure the solution is something incredibly simple, but I just can't seem to solve this, although I've done a lot of research already.

Here's the response returned to the client from the /account/create request:

```
{
    "auth": true,
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InRlc3QyIiwiaWF0IjoxNjMzNzg3MjE2fQ.duo5R9wXpk2Gj-iPHFMaDgKK0p3h6WZf5vnXrZViePo"
}
```

EDIT: Turns out that the token does not go the header, but to the body. What do I need to do differently to get it passed to the header?

Comment: are you sure the result of calling "/account/create" API with 200 status will return the token correctly?

Comment: please share your client-side codes which are related to set the token in the header. you can also check this in the chrome network tab by inspecting the API call and check its header. is the token attached and sent correctly via API calls?

Comment: @novonimo I did some edits to the question, including the rest of the login request and the response given by the /account/create request

Comment: as I mentioned before please add the client-side related code

Comment: @novonimo What do you mean by client-side related code? The frontend for this is an Android app, do you mean that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it looks like I had understood this wrong.

I thought that the token has to be always returned and received in a header. This is not the case. The token response from /account/create has to be in the body. The token has to be set to the header only, when triggering the /account/login request (authenticating the login).

Hopefully this might help someone having the same question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In the `result == null` case, you have three statements that send a response: two asynchronous `res.status(404)` statements and one synchronous `res.status(200)` statement. Only of them may be executed per request.

But with the current code, the status 200 statement is executed for *every* request, even if a failed database operation later leads to an additional status 404 statement, which then causes the observed error.

Comment: I changed the code so that response code 200 is only returned when all the database operations are completed successfully, but the end result is the same.